# Does Oracle have a time-to-live feature for rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

In Cassandra I am used to the `USING TTL` clause of upserts which sets a number of seconds after which the upserted data will be deleted.

Does Oracle have a feature like this? I haven't been able to find anything about it.

Comment: A bit different database models..

Comment: @user2864740 Certainly, but the concept of row expiry is not something that only makes sense in a distributed NoSQL database.

Comment: Oracle has the concept of *retaining* data at all costs, until you explicitly ask it to delete it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are ways to implement this feature, but I don't believe it is built in.  The easiest way is to have a `CreatedAt` column in the table that specifies when a row has been inserted.  Then, create a view to get the most recent rows, so for the most recent day:

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*
    from table t
    where t.CreatedAt >= sysdate - 1;
```

This fixes the data access side.  To actually delete the rows, you need an additional job to periodically delete old rows in the table.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide an example of an additional job to periodically delete old rows?

Comment: @2rs2ts . . . The job is essentially `delete from table where CreatedAt < sysdate - 1` (for some value of "1").  This then needs to be scheduled, either using Oracle's built-in mechanisms or using an external job scheduler.  Note:  I would suggest you put an index on `createdAt`.

Comment: Thanks so much. Would it also work if I used a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` field and set it to `SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '3600' SECOND(4)` for a user specifying a time-to-live of 3600 seconds? Then my `where` clause in the view could be `t.expireAfter > SYSTIMESTAMP`? We already built an API that uses seconds (because that's what Cassandra uses), so if this works, then it would be the simplest for us to implement.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that approach will work, so long as `createdAt` also has a similar declaration (`timestamp with time zone`).

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what you mean by "Oracle".

Oracle relational database does not have it out of the box. We have usually scheduled a stored procedure to perform such tasks.

[Oracle NoSQL database](https://docs.oracle.com/database/nosql-12.1.4.0/) [has it](https://docs.oracle.com/database/nosql-12.1.4.0/GettingStartedGuideTables/timetolive.html):

> Time to Live (TTL) is a mechanism that allows you to automatically expire table rows. TTL is expressed as the amount of time data is allowed to live in the store. Data which has reached its expiration timeout value can no longer be retrieved, and will not appear in any store statistics. Whether the data is physically removed from the store is determined by an internal mechanism that is not user-controllable.